# How can I invert any key frames to start the animation from the last key frame?

Tags: animation, keyframes

So recently I've found a cool tutorial on youtube about disintegrating a text. The text gets vanished over time. I want the same effect but I want to reveal the text out of nothing. My question is how can I make the last key frame to be the first key frame?
In case anyone want to see the video here is the link.
https://youtu.be/wm4rDDRcbDQ

Answer (score 3):

Set your marker right in the middle of your frames (e.g. if you have 500 frames, set it on 250), mark all keyframes, then right click and then choose

mirror by times over current frame

[image]

[image]